# Não faz nada ao tentar abrir popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**No HTML**

Eu tenho este **footer** :

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toogle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="c">
                    <ul>
                       <li><a class = "nav" href="#" id="btnCl">1</a></li>
                       <li><a class = "ui-btn-active  nav" href="#">2</a></li>
                       <li><a class = "nav" href="#" >3</a></li>
                       <li><a class = "nav" href="#" id="btnDef">4</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
</div>
```

E criei esta **popup** :

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupMenu" data-theme="b">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;">
            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

E criei na página **JavaScript** esta função que deveria, quando se clica no `tab 1` do `footer` abrir a `popup`:

```
$('#btnCl').click(function () {
        $("#popupMenu").popup("open");
    });
```

**Problema:**

Quando se carrega no `tab 1` do `footer` nada acontece...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Popups jQuery Mobile

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
<p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.</p>
</div>
```

Site do projeto: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/

Não esqueça de linkar sempre os endereços do jQuery Mobile. Basta escolher seu modelo e adaptar as tags html, clique em **View Source**

---

## Para popups

Use esta função javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
</script>
```

No link `a href`utilize o `onClick="MM_openBrWindow('http://google.com','popup1','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=500,height=500')"`

## Resultado

Neste exmplo a popup abre ao clicar no link 1
https://jsfiddle.net/tiagoboeing/nhmwfdpm/

## Atributos possíveis

*Neste exemplo está como **google.com** para exibir
**Popup 1:** nome da sua janela, chamada javascript
**Scrollbars:** mostra barra de rolagem se necessário (yes, no) 
**Resizable:** deixa redimensionar a janela (yes, no) 
**Width:** largura da janela (em pixels) 
**Height:** altura da janela (em pixels) 
**menubar:** mostra barra de menus (yes, no) 
**toolbar:** barra de ferramentas (yes, no) 
**status:** barra de status (yes, no)

Comment: Eu não pretendo que a popup aberta seja uma janela nova. Eu estava a tentar fazer uma coisa deste genero http://prntscr.com/7php72

Comment: Você quer um lightbox com um conteúdo dentro, correto?

Comment: Confira um exemplo do `colorbox`: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ Clique sobre inline html

Comment: sim, algo do genero. Que quando clico, neste caso, no 1º tab, me abre essa janelita com os 4 botões

Comment: Eu estava a tentar basear-me nisto: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/#&ui-state=dialog (no exemplo da **dialog**)